# Matplotlib 3DPlot Extra Lines when Dimensions not Equal

Tags: python, matplotlib

Consider this MWE:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from mpl_toolkits.mplot3d import Axes3D
import numpy as np
from matplotlib import cm

n = 15
m = 12

x = np.linspace(-5, 5, n)
y = np.linspace(-5, 5, m)

Z = np.zeros((m, n))
for i in xrange(m):
    for j in xrange(n):
        Z[i, j] = x[j]**2 + y[i]**2


### Plot surface ###
fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.add_subplot(111, projection='3d')
X, Y = np.meshgrid(x, y)
ax.plot_surface(X, Y, Z)
ax.set_xlabel('x')
ax.set_ylabel('y')
ax.set_zlabel('Z')
plt.show()
```

Note in particular that the dimensions `n` and `m` are not equal.  The resulting plot has some weird lines hanging down, as well as strange coloring: [image: plot]

What's going on here, and how can I prevent this?

Comment: isn't `15` and `12` really really low for the number of samples? like if you instead did `n = 150 ; m = 120` it seems to show correctly, I think it is just extreme low detail 3d shape isn't showing correctly because... it is insufficient detail.

Answer (score 2):

Unlike 2D, 3D plots in matplotlib have a lot of [shortcomings](http://matplotlib.org/mpl_toolkits/mplot3d/faq.html). Let me quote one of the answers in matplotlib FAQ:

> This is probably the most commonly reported issue with mplot3d. The
>   problem is that – from some viewing angles – a 3D object would appear
>   in front of another object, even though it is physically behind it.
>   This can result in plots that do not look “physically correct.”
>
> Unfortunately, while some work is being done to reduce the occurance
>   of this artifact, it is currently an intractable problem, and can not
>   be fully solved until matplotlib supports 3D graphics rendering at its
>   core.
>
> The problem occurs due to the reduction of 3D data down to 2D +
>   z-order scalar. A single value represents the 3rd dimension for all
>   parts of 3D objects in a collection. Therefore, when the bounding
>   boxes of two collections intersect, it becomes possible for this
>   artifact to occur. Furthermore, the intersection of two 3D objects
>   (such as polygons or patches) can not be rendered properly in
>   matplotlib’s 2D rendering engine.
>
> This problem will likely not be solved until OpenGL support is added
>   to all of the backends (patches are greatly welcomed). Until then, if
>   you need complex 3D scenes, we recommend using MayaVi.

For your particular problem (and notice that I don't think this has anything to do with different sizes in each direction) I would advise you to increase your surface shape (even if artificially) and play around with the number of strides until you obtain something that is satisfactory:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from mpl_toolkits.mplot3d import Axes3D
import numpy as np
from matplotlib import cm

n = 150
m = 120

x = np.linspace(-5, 5, n)
y = np.linspace(-5, 5, m)

Z = np.zeros((m, n))
for i in range(m):
    for j in range(n):
        Z[i, j] = x[j]**2 + y[i]**2


### Plot surface ###
fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.add_subplot(111, projection='3d')
X, Y = np.meshgrid(x, y)
ax.plot_surface(X, Y, Z,rstride=1, cstride=1)
ax.set_xlabel('x')
ax.set_ylabel('y')
ax.set_zlabel('Z')
plt.show()
```

,which results in this:

[image: Matplotlib surface with rstrides and cstrides == 10]

The example above give rstrides and cstrides a value of 10. Should you increase it too much (let's say 80) and the problem becomes obvious:

[image: Matplotlib surface with rstrides and cstrides == 80]

Other option is for you to follow the recommendation of matplotlib FAQ itself and check [Mayavi](http://code.enthought.com/projects/mayavi/documentation.php). Notice, however, that mayavi still does not support Python 3. Personally, if you need something quick to work with, I would recommend [PyQtGraph](http://www.pyqtgraph.org/).